# Writing a MySQL statement with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, they are:

```
job, community, state, and region.
```

Their structure is as follows:

```
job:
columns:
  id
  community_id
relations:
  community:  local_key: community_id, foreign_key: id

community:
columns:
  id
  state_id
relations: 
  state: local_key: state_id, foreign_key: id

state:
columns:
  id
  name
  region_id
relations:
  region: local_key: region_id, foreign_key: id

region:
columns:
  id
  name
```

Now, I need a query that will:

```
get all the jobs with matching communities: i.e.: j.community_id = c.id

then, from those matches, get all of the jobs in communities with a state region_id = "1"
```

I do fine, pulling the state, but I get stuck trying to pull in the region.  I got this far:

```
SELECT j.id
FROM job j
INNER JOIN community c
ON j.community_id = c.id
WHERE c.state_id = 35
```

I'm not even sure if my tables are set up correcty in order to retrieve this info.  Any help getting me over the hump would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I think it's what you want.

```
SELECT
    r.name AS regionname,
    s.name AS statename
FROM
    job j
LEFT JOIN
    community c ON c.id = j.community_id
LEFT JOIN
    state s ON s.id = c.state_id
LEFT JOIN
    region r ON r.id = s.region_id
WHERE
    r.id = 1
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, +1 on the question for clear db structure